# Why do my tile textures keep resampling/blurring?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I set up a tilemapnode in my gamescene.sks file and the tiles are 16px by 16px but are scaled up to 128 pixels. They look fine at first but if I start editing or adding new tiles later on the old tiles get resampled automatically and look extremely blurry compared to the new tiles. Any idea why its doing this and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean add new tiles later on?  Like at Runtime?  it sounds like you are not properly handling how the retina works, where at compile time it is generating the 1x 2x 3x graphics for you, but at runtime you are adding a new tile that is not the same size as the old tile in whatever retina mode you are in (Basically you are adding a 16x16 graphic when you really should be adding a 32x32 graphic) , thus causing the old tile to  use the wrong graphic and scale via the gpu